# Skip .htaccess rules for some particular files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

Now i am using the following .htaccess rules to modify my urls.My website contains more images and similar files.I found that .htaccess rules increases site's loading time.I wish to skip execution of some codes for domain.com/images and domain.com/scripts folders.

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^.]+).html index.php?perma=$3
RewriteRule ^movies/([^.]+).html gallery.php?movie=$1
RewriteRule ^album/([^.]+).html gallery.php?album=$1
RewriteRule ^img/([^.]+)/([^.]+).html gallery.php?img=$2
RewriteRule ^movies.html gallery.php

i want to modify it to

if it is a file in image or script folder skip following
else
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^.]+).html index.php?perma=$3
else 
RewriteRule ^movies/([^.]+).html gallery.php?movie=$1
else
RewriteRule ^album/([^.]+).html gallery.php?album=$1
else
RewriteRule ^img/([^.]+)/([^.]+).html gallery.php?img=$2
else
RewriteRule ^movies.html gallery.php

Any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having one .htaccess file put one in, for example, the movies folder with the RewriteRule for the movies folder or put one in the img folder with only the RewriteRule that is used in/for the /img/ folder. This means that it will load different .htaccess files based on its directory instead of using one.